# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value may not be null. when putting data in ParseObject

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am following a course on Udemy and I'm on a section where we created an anonymous user and after an Activity, tried to set the AnonUsername into a put method in ParseObject. I get the above error in the title when I use:

```
put("riderUsername", ParseObject.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
```

But I get the "com.parse.ParseUser...." when i use:

```
put("riderUsername", ParseObject.getCurrentUser());
```

This is my code for when I press a button to send this to Parse:

```
public void toggleSearch(View view){

    ParseObject request = new ParseObject("Requests");
    request.put("requestUsername", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().toString());

    ParseACL acl = new ParseACL();
    acl.setPublicWriteAccess(true);
    acl.setPublicReadAccess(true);

    request.setACL(acl);

    request.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if(e == null){
                driverStatus.setText("Searching Drivers...");
            } else {
                driverStatus.setText("Error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

And this is where I created the Anon user in the first Activity:

```
if(ParseUser.getCurrentUser() == null) {
        ParseAnonymousUtils.logIn(new LogInCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.i("App Data", "Logged In");
                } else {
                    Log.i("App Data", "Not Logged In");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Tried searching but couldn't find anything. Just hoping there might be something someone else knows that I'm doing wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can do

```
put("riderUsername", ParseObject.getCurrentUser());
```

without problems, but this one fails and throws the exception:

```
put("riderUsername", ParseObject.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
```

Of course, ParseObject.getCurrentUser() is not null because you can store it and also because `ParseObject.getCurrentUser().getUsername()` would throw a `java.lang.NullPointerException`

So, the only possibility is that the user name stored in current user is null.

Check that the user name is not null in your Login callback for the parameter `ParseUser user`. You can use as well this method:

```
ParseUser.getUsername()
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply Jorge. The thing with setting up the AnonUser is that the Parse class sets the username itself. So when checking in the table its jargon which is fine but that isn't given back when you try to access the user which is current. I think I will just set up the Login and Sign in normally as the trainer didn't add it.